# Why am I getting an "invalid blogml" error importing into BlogEngine.net

Tags: wordpress, blog

I have a WordPress blog that is hosted on `hostgator.com`. I am looking at switching to BlogEngine.net. I found the BlogML project up on CodePlex to help with the migration. It has a tool called  "WordPress BlogML Export 1.0a". This is a replacement for `export.php` which can be uploaded to `wp-admin/` on a WordPress blog.

I did this and then exported my blog from WordPress using this new export script. However, when I use the BlogEngine.net import tool, and give it my exported BlogMl file, it says "Invalid BlogML."

Any idea on what might be invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the source code to the [BlogML project](http://blogml.codeplex.com/releases/view/34405) and use the binary in the

```
Schema Validator\bin\Release
```

directory to see what problems your BlogML file has. If there aren't any, the problem is probably on their end.

Comment: Once I got the schema file, it pointed out all the errors. Thanks a ton!